# How to relate two columns in Microsoft excel

Tags: excel, algorithm, ms-office

Lets imagine two columns Request and Time. If I enter a request in cell A1 I should get the system time in Cell B1. For entire column. Can anyone help me with the solution?
Hi i would like to know what should I do to get the system time in a protected field. Example:- If I enter anything in Column A will give the system time on Column B in the respective cell. What if the entire column B is protected? –

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to record the time an entry is made anywhere in column **A**.  We want the time to be recorded in the adjacent column (column **B**)

Further we want the time to be *static*.

Inset the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, intR As Range
    Set rng = Range("A:A")
    Set intR = Intersect(Target, rng)
    If intR Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In intR
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now - Date
            r.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Just a simple doubt. Where does it mentioned as Column 1 and Column 2? I mean A and B.

Comment: @Skywatcher  A very good question....column **A** comes from `Range("A:A")` and column **B** comes from the `OFFSET()`